# Need help using an svg as a background divider on my home page

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I'm trying to have a wave shape as a divider on my page which also interacts with overlayed text. Anyways I have mocked it up in adobe XD for [mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/222YP.png) as well as for  [desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjE88.png) and don't know how to translate that into code. I tried using an svg but it ended up looking like [this on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD8lZ.png) and [like this on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djTQR.png) . I'm think using an svg for the line is the best way to go about this, but just can't seem to get the css right.

The svg file looks like:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}</style></defs><polygon class="cls-1" points="0.5 86.54 173.5 0.54 292.5 43.54 398.5 66.54 486.5 43.54 592.5 31.54 738.5 83.54 916.5 31.54 1000.5 43.54 1000.5 1000.54 0.5 1000.54 0.5 86.54"/></svg>
```

and my css looks like:

```
.waves {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #B0E0E6; 
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and in my html is `<img src={waves} alt="Background Waves" className="waves"></img>`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with your CSS? The main problem seems to be with your SVG, which isn't filled with blue.

Comment: @kmoser I don't know if anything is wrong with my css, just posting for clarity. And Yea I can fill the svg with blue, thanks for the tip. But that doesn't solve the fact that the svg isn't spanning the width of the page and also won't scale along heigh wise either. Looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/reR9rIY) now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out myself! I needed to add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to my SVG file.